How to declare the constructor with exactly nRow*nCol arguments of type T?
I am a newbie in C++ and just learned how to use templates.
I want to write a Matrix class with the following template arguments:
template < int nRow ,int nCol ,typename T = double >
class ZDMatrix  {
public:
    ZDMatrix();
    ZDMatrix( T arg0 );
    ZDMatrix( T arg0 ,T arg1 );
    // ... How to declare the constructor with exactly nRow*nCol arguments of type T ??
    // ZDMatrix( T arg0 ,T arg1 ,... ) {
    //     ... number or argN should be nRow*nCol
    // }
};

I want to be able to use the matrix like this:
ZDMatrix<2,3>   matX( 1 ,1.1 ,1.2 ,2,2.1,2.2 );  // auto convert int 1 to double 1.0

As an alternative, I already try using std::initializer_list:
ZDMatrix<nRow,nCol,double>::ZDMatrix( std::initializer_list<T> list )  {
    assert( list.size() == nRow*nCol );
    // ...
}

But the check for the number of arguments is at run time not static_assert().

std::array<T, nRow * nCol> args

There are multiple problems with the assert macro. One of them is that the check is at run-time, as you noted. Another is that if the assertion fail the program will crash, with no possibility for you to catch it or to recover. And if the macro NDEBUG is defined, which is common for release builds, then the macro does nothing at all.

On a different note, for sizes I recommend you use the type std::size_t instead of int.

sizeof... returns the length of a template parameter pack

In this case you can't get away from a runtime check if you use std::initializer_list<T>, but you can use template parameter packs as mentioned by @Raildex. Yes it will allow the user of your class to use many different types for arguments, but you will get an error at compile-time if the type is not implicitly convertible to T when you copy the values.


How do you declare the constructor with exactly nRow*nCol arguments of type T ??

One way is by using sizeof..., the number of elements in a parameter pack can be checked, assuming you use the constructor with variadic template arguments. Applying SFINAE, it would look like:
#include <type_traits> // std::conjunction (since c++17), std::enable_if, std::is_same

template <std::size_t nRow, std::size_t nCol, typename T = double>
class ZDMatrix
{
   std::array<T, nRow* nCol> mData{};

public:
   template <typename... Ts, 
      std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == nRow * nCol &&  // No. of args must be equal tonRow * nCol
      std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>>...> // or std::is_convertible, std::decay_t<Ts>
      >* = nullptr>
      ZDMatrix(Ts&&... args)
      : mData{ std::forward<Ts>(args)... }
   {}
};

See live demo

Alternatively, you could static_assert the above two SFINAE conditions inside the constructor body. Or in C++20 you would do requires  constraints for the same conditions as shown below:
template <std::size_t nRow, std::size_t nCol, typename T = double>
class ZDMatrix
{
   std::array<T, nRow* nCol> mData{};

public:
   template <typename... Ts>
      requires (sizeof...(Ts) == nRow * nCol) && (std::same_as<T, std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>> && ...)
   ZDMatrix(Ts&&... args)
      : mData{ std::forward<Ts>(args)... }
   {}
};

See live demo

As a side note, the compiler will always tell the type mismatch while using the templated constructor. I would choose a template solution unless there is a special requirement to have std::initializer_list<T> and assert macro.

Great C++20 features, simplified a lot of things
